# Email Configuration laravel app for pagoda box

Tags: laravel-4, pagoda-box

Recently i deployed my laravel app to pagoda box, Its working fine except the email. In my app there is registration for the user's, When they get register they will get mail. This functionality is working fine in localhost but it seems i am missing some configuration on pagoda box, The credentials for mail in my app is as follows.

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'username@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
'password' => 'password',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

And the credentials for the pagoda box is as follows,

```
SMTP Host: Gmail
Email/Username: username@gmail.com
Password:password
Outgoing Email Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port Number: 587
TLS: Yes
Auth Type: plain
```

And the POP and IMAP both are enabled for my gmail account.
The error i am getting is,

Swift_TransportException

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and              Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 x14sm24451446obp.19 - gsmtp "
```

And i tried with changing the email address and port but no use.
Am i missing something ? or i need to do an changes in credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this settings worked for me:

```
return array(
  'driver' => 'smtp',
  'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  'port' => 587,
  'from' => array('address' => 'yourusername@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test from laravel'),
  'encryption' => 'tls',
  'username' => 'yourusername@gmail.com',
  'password' => 'yourpassword',
  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
  'pretend' => false,

);
```

If you're still having problems, visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password. If necessary, enter the letters in the distorted picture.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257